# How can I avoid zlib "unexpected end of file" when GUnzipping partial files?

Tags: node.js, zlib

I'm trying to read part of a gzipped file while decompressing it so I can parse the header contents without reading uneccessary bytes. I had this working previously using `fs.read()` while passing options to only read the first 500 bytes then using `zlib.gunzip()` to decompress the contents before parsing the header from the binary data.

This was working fine until node v5.0.0 patched a bug to ensure zlib throws an error on a truncated input (https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/2595).

Now I'm getting the following error from zlib.

```
Error: unexpected end of file
```

How can I unzip this partial file knowing that I'm truncating the input without throwing an error. I was thinking it might be easier with streams so I wrote the following.

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path, {start: 0, end: 500});
var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();

readStream.pipe(gunzip)
    .on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log(parseBinaryHeader(chunk));
        console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length);
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log('end');
    });
```

My `parseBinaryHeader()` function is returning the correct header content so I know it's unzipping but it's still throwing an error when it hits the end of the input. I can add the error listener to handle the error and do nothing with it, but this doesn't seem ideal.

Any ideas?

Comment: don't feed in truncated files? it SHOULD be warning you about the fact that the input is basically corrupt.

Comment: So how can I work around the larger issue of needing to efficiently read the headers of a bunch of files while not caring about the rest of the contents. File numbers and size vary, but I'm generally reading 30+ files that total 2 - 5GB. I only need about the first 500 bytes of each files. I've tried reading every file in it's entirety but the performance difference is pretty dramatic.

Comment: try/catch the errors? unless zlib has a "ignore errors" flag you can enable, then you're stuck with what it's going to spit out, or could just write your own unzip library.

Comment: Can you use `zlib.createGunzip` or `zlib.createGunzipSync` directly without the stream? You should be able to feed it portions of compressed data and the available uncompressed data. Once you've gotten what you're after, kill the objects.

Comment: Thanks @MarkAdler . I did something very similar to this. I wrote a single chunk to the Gunzip stream and then immediately paused the stream to avoid the unexpected end of file. This has allowed me to continue handling all other gunzip errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions. I also submitted a question issue to the node repository and got some good feedback. Here's what ended up working for me.

- Set the chunk size to the full header size.
- Write the single chunk to the decompress stream and immediately pause the stream.
- Handle the decompressed chunk.

example

```
var bytesRead = 500;
var decompressStream = zlib.createGunzip()
    .on('data', function (chunk) {
        parseHeader(chunk);
        decompressStream.pause();
    }).on('error', function(err) {
        handleGunzipError(err, file, chunk);
    });

fs.createReadStream(file.path, {start: 0, end: bytesRead, chunkSize: bytesRead + 1})
    .on('data', function (chunk) {
        decompressStream.write(chunk);
    });
```

This has been working so far and also allows me to keep handling all other gunzip errors as the pause() prevents the decompress stream from throwing the "unexpected end of file" error.

Comment: where does parseHeader(chunk) come from?
in my case, it says parseHeader is not defined

Comment: This answer is unfortunately incomplete. `parseHeader` is not defined, nor is `handleGunzipError`. So could you kindly explain how to parse a gzip chunk without the "Unexpected End Of File" error being thrown?

Comment: @h0r53 For the context of this question the specifics of `parseHeader` and `handleGunzipError` don't really matter. You can replace them with `console.log` and handle the contents of each however you'd like. `chunk` is just a decompressed portion of a file. How you parse it will depend on what type of file it is and your specific needs. You may not even need to parse if further.

Comment: @Constellates I thought the point of `chunk` was to send fragments of data, and in the case of `gzip` + `chunk` the data is first compressed via `gzip`, then it is chunked across one or more packets. Is this not the case?

Comment: @h0r53 That's close. In this example I'm opening a stream to read a file. That file is already gzipped. Every time the file stream reads a new chunk of data from that gzipped file it calls `decompressStream.write` with it. In turn the zlib gunzip object (`decompressStream`) un-gzips each chunk and passes the unzipped file chunk to `parseHeader`. So if you replaced that with console.log you should see pieces of unzipped file.

Comment: I see. For my purposes I'm attempting to decompress chunked gzip data as a part of HTTP messages. I have a collection of HTTP responses, but my attempts to decompress chunked gzip transfer encodings result in the unexpected EOF error when the compressed data is large enough (presumably across multiple packets / HTTP responses).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this when piping a `net.Socket` into a decompression `zlib.createInflate()` stream.

```js
const net = require('net')
const zlib = require('zlib')

net.connect(port, host)
  .pipe(zlib.createInflate())
  .on('data', chunk => console.log('chunk', chunk))
```

When the socket closed, the zlib stream would throw the unexpected end of file error because it was ended with partial state.

I fixed it by setting `finishFlush: zlib.constants.Z_SYNC_FLUSH` so that it flushes partial data instead of expecting to seal a complete block with Z_FINISH eof.

```js
const net = require('net')
const zlib = require('zlib')

net.connect(port, host)
  .pipe(zlib.createInflate({
    finishFlush: zlib.constants.Z_SYNC_FLUSH,
  }))
  .on('data', chunk => console.log('chunk', chunk))
```

Comment: Pretty good answer! Share my case as FYI - a big compressed CSV file sitting in cloud storage, I only need to fetch the first 1MB for preview, having partial decompression saves a ton, and we don't need streaming with a 1MB buffer. This option exactly fixes the error of calling gunzipSync - "unexpected end of file". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when trying to end processing of a NodeJS Gzip stream. I used "buffer-peek-stream" to inspect the header of the gzip stream - determining that it is in fact a gzip stream. Then I unwrapped the first few megabytes of the stream - to peek inside that file and determine the mime type of the gzip contents.

This necessitated two calls to zlib.createGunzip()

I found that even if I created what appeared to be two separate instances of the gunzip transform, destroying the second instance caused the first instance to throw this "unexpected end of file" error. Even when the first instance was in a completely different context.

The fix in my case was to call .destroy() on the first instance to clean it up, before creating a second instance.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using node v10.13.0. I upgraded to v10.19.0 and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Constellates' answer works great, but only if the extractable chunk is smaller than zlib's processing chunk size (16 KB by default). For larger amounts, you need to combine the chunks, for example by concatenating them. Here is a TS example using Promises:

```js
const gunzipped: Buffer = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const buffer_builder: Buffer[] = []
    const decompress_stream = zlib.createGunzip()
        .on('data', (chunk: Buffer) => {
            buffer_builder.push(chunk)
        }).on('close', () => {
            resolve(Buffer.concat(buffer_builder))
        }).on('error', (err) => {
            if(err.errno !== -5) // EOF: expected
                reject(err)
        });
    decompress_stream.write(/* ... your gzipped input buffer */)
    decompress_stream.end()
})
```